# Converting unix time to datetime with FROM_UNIXTIME() in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Table:

[image]

I'm wondering if there is a way to convert all my timestamps into native mysql datetime (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`) using FROM_UNIXTIME(), but I'm falling short on examples I can pull from. MySQL is not my kung fu.

Comment: `FROM_UNIXTIME` is exactly what does it. What is your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to replace the unix timestamp field with a native mysql datetime field. To do this, you'd need to add a new field to your table of the datetime type:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD newdatetimefield DATETIME NOT NULL;
```

Then do an update on your table:

```
update yourtable set newdatetimefield=from_unixtime(timestampfield);
```

Then you can drop the old unix timestamp field:

```
alter table yourtable drop timestampfield;
```

and rename the new field to the old name

```
alter table yourtable change newdatetimefield timestampfield datetime;
```

Comment: Also: If there is one or more `index` on `timestampfield` or `foreign key` in other table that reference `timestampfield`: Add new indexes and references on your `newdatetimefield` and drop the old ones.